# What does "read -n1 -s" mean in this script?

Tags: bash, read, case

Today I have learned some tricks about menu option in command line.
One of these was

```
cat << EOF
    Some lines
EOF
read -n1 -s
case $newvar in
   "1") echo "";
ecsa
```

It's really magical.
I can't find any description in man page about this option. How the input to **read** command was pushed into **case** option ? It usually use a variable to do this thing as I know.

I just want to understand the process of this combination further.

```
while :
do
    clear
    cat<<EOF
    ==============================
    Menu Install DHCP Tool
    ------------------------------
    Please enter your choice:

    (1) Config Network Interface
    (2) Check status
    (3) Config DHCP server
    (Q)uit
    ------------------------------
EOF
read -n1 -s
    case "$REPLY" in
    "1")  config_network ;;
    "2")  check_status ;;
    "3")  config_dhcp ;;
    "q")  exit                      ;;
     * )  echo "invalid option"     ;;
    esac
    sleep 0.2
done
```

Comment: Post your *actual code*.

Comment: Added as you wish.

Comment: IMHO, this is a pretty convoluted way to create a menu, `bash` has an inbuilt menu system for doing what you have described, and allows you to use less code, which means its more readable. you can find documentation on it here `man bash | less '+/^\s*select'`

Comment: @the_velour_fog, Seems rather straightforward to me. And doing it manually allows control over how it looks and what the hotkeys are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation of `read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) notes that:

> If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable `REPLY`.

From that point it's a normal `case` statement. `-n1` reads a single byte and `-s` turns off terminal echo of the input.

Comment: And how about option -n1 -s , what does it mean ?

Comment: `-n1` reads a single byte and `-s` turns off terminal echo. They are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$newvar` you use in your short description doesn't exist.

It must be `$REPLY`, as you actually use in the full command.

This issues have no relation to the read options `-n1 -s` you are asking about.